# Java based configuration for Spring imap-idle-channel-adapter

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I try to find answer in google. It wasn't successful. Is it possible to configure `imap-idle-channel-adapter` using Spring java based configuration.

I want to get inbox messages for current authenticated in application user. It means I can't hardcode username and password for store-uri.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just wire an `ImapMailReceiver` into an `ImapIdleChannelAdapter`.

But if you just want to fetch the messages for a user once; simply create an `ImapMailReceiver` with the URL for that user, and call `receive()`.